# How to loop through JSON

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, bing-api

I am trying to loop through this JSON in order to get to the 'name' parameter. The data comes from Microsoft's Bing API. I can pass in coordinates to get the name of a place. I have pasted the response below. as well as my attempt. Please assist.

```
{  
   "authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials",
   "brandLogoUri":"http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png",
   "copyright":"Copyright © 2018 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
   "resourceSets":[  
      {  
         "estimatedTotal":1,
         "resources":[  
            {  
               "__type":"Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
               "bbox":[  
                  47.636677282429325,
                  -122.13698331308882,
                  47.64440271757068,
                  -122.12169668691118
               ],
               "name":"1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
               "point":{  
                  "type":"Point",
                  "coordinates":[  
                     47.64054,
                     -122.12934
                  ]
               },
               "address":{  
                  "addressLine":"1 Microsoft Way",
                  "adminDistrict":"WA",
                  "adminDistrict2":"King Co.",
                  "countryRegion":"United States",
                  "formattedAddress":"1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
                  "locality":"Redmond",
                  "postalCode":"98052"
               },
               "confidence":"Medium",
               "entityType":"Address",
               "geocodePoints":[  
                  {  
                     "type":"Point",
                     "coordinates":[  
                        47.64054,
                        -122.12934
                     ],
                     "calculationMethod":"Interpolation",
                     "usageTypes":[  
                        "Display",
                        "Route"
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "matchCodes":[  
                  "Good"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "statusCode":200,
   "statusDescription":"OK",
   "traceId":"089a91ac5b694010884d6a7b7d245718|CH12F221B8|7.7.0.0|CH1AAPBD7C89012"
}
```

I have tried the following but am getting a length undefined error:

```
this.http.get('http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/'+this.latitude+','+this.longitide+'?o=json&key=AgThwaQToIr5UwjAisaBegjG3qpxBfgFL354mlTxiRPGOrqId8nShnugy40jpebW').subscribe(data => {
  this.place = data;
  for(var i; i < this.place.resourceSets.length; i++){
    this.dataset = this.place.resourceSets[i].resources;
    console.log(this.dataset);
  }
  }) 
}
```

Comment: what is `this.place`?

Comment: just a global variable

Comment: need more info like codekaizer mentioned, also any debugging. undefined could be anything, which line of code said it was undefined?

Comment: how you can get global variable as a  property of object\

Comment: unfortunately programmers usually aren't good mind readers. please post the full json object including posting what `this.place` is ?

Comment: @Akshaypadwal You can when `this === window`.

Comment: this is the full json

Comment: @ Scott Marcus yeah i know but above json does not contains place so how can he use this.place

Comment: ok so can you explain how `this.place` and the results from the API have anything to do with eachother?

Comment: yes the data from the response is assigned to this.place

Comment: Is it just me, or is i not initialized?

Comment: edited above to show this, my problem is just the looping

Comment: your loop has problem initialise i = 0 then it will work

Comment: ok thanks akshay, will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a big part of your problem is you're using `this` for your local variable assignments.  Ideally you should use `let` but for backwards compatible browsers you can always use `var`.

See below, especially the loop, which performs `var dataset` and also caches the length to the variable `n`:

```js
var place = {
  "authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
  "brandLogoUri": "http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png",
  "copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
  "resourceSets": [{
    "estimatedTotal": 1,
    "resources": [{
      "__type": "Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
      "bbox": [
        47.636677282429325, -122.13698331308882,
        47.64440271757068, -122.12169668691118
      ],
      "name": "1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
      "point": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          47.64054, -122.12934
        ]
      },
      "address": {
        "addressLine": "1 Microsoft Way",
        "adminDistrict": "WA",
        "adminDistrict2": "King Co.",
        "countryRegion": "United States",
        "formattedAddress": "1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
        "locality": "Redmond",
        "postalCode": "98052"
      },
      "confidence": "Medium",
      "entityType": "Address",
      "geocodePoints": [{
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          47.64054, -122.12934
        ],
        "calculationMethod": "Interpolation",
        "usageTypes": [
          "Display",
          "Route"
        ]
      }],
      "matchCodes": [
        "Good"
      ]
    }]
  }],
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusDescription": "OK",
  "traceId": "089a91ac5b694010884d6a7b7d245718|CH12F221B8|7.7.0.0|CH1AAPBD7C89012"
}


for (var i=0,n=place.resourceSets.length; i<n; i++) {
  var dataset = place.resourceSets[i].resources;
  console.log(dataset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code for your question :--

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var text = '{ "data":{"rule":[{"clauses":{ "id":"q", "act":"the", "r":"1","cond":"2"}, "data":{"cond_oper":"7"}},{"clauses":{"id":"qw","act":"thefir","r":"1","cond":"1"},"data":{ "cond_oper":"7"}}]}}';
      var obj = JSON.parse(text);
      console.log(obj.data.rule.length);
      alert(obj.data.rule.length);

//Get the count 
// var count = obj.data.rule.length

      for(var i=0; i<obj.data.rule.length; i++)
      {
         alert(obj.data.rule[i].clauses.id);
         console.log(obj.data.rule[i].clauses.id)
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `var i;`, `i` is not being initialized only declared. Initializing `i` with `= 0` this works fine locally for me using a sample lat/long.

```
$.get('http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.640568390488625,-122.1293731033802?o=json&key=AgThwaQToIr5UwjAisaBegjG3qpxBfgFL354mlTxiRPGOrqId8nShnugy40jpebW',function(data){
    this.place = data;
    console.log(this.place.resourceSets.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < this.place.resourceSets.length; i++){
      console.log(this.place.resourceSets[0]);
    }
  });
});
```